# "Выполнить" текстовую переменную в Java

Tags: java, android, eval

Возможно, есть специальная функция в Java (из коробки, либо из библиотек), аналогичная функции `eval` из таких языков, как `PHP` и `JS`?

К примеру, дано:

```
a="5+3";
```

Выполнение функции:

```
return eval(a); // Вернёт 8
```

Мои поиски такой функции среди других функций в разных официальных библиотеках ни к чему не привели

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Comment: Или вот: http://vampirus.ru/code/dynamic-compile-java/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ява из коробки такого не умеет, ибо это в яве, ИМХО, не нужно. Зато вы можете зупустить JavaScript явой, а вот он уже это [умеет](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form):

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    String foo = "40+2";
    System.out.println(engine.eval(foo));
    } 
}
```

---

Либо попробуйте либу [js-evaluator-for-android](https://github.com/evgenyneu/js-evaluator-for-android)

Подключаем

build.gradle файл проекта:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

build.gradle файл модуля app:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // Keep you existing dependencies here
    compile 'com.github.evgenyneu:js-evaluator-for-android:v1.0.7'
}
```

Используем:

```
JsEvaluator jsEvaluator = new JsEvaluator(this);
jsEvaluator.evaluate("2 * 17", new JsCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onResult(final String result) {
    // Process result here.
    // This method is called in the UI thread.
    Log.d("MyTag", result);
  }
});
```

Comment: как его запустить? не импортируется такая библиотека, её качать надо?

Comment: @EgorRandomize, возможно, первый вариант в андроиде и не покатит. Посмотрите другой вариант в дополнении ответа. А вообще - зачем вам такую задачу на адроиде на яве решать?

Comment: на работе требуют знания явы, многодейственный калькулятор был бы отличной демонстрацией)

Comment: @EgorRandomize, ну, таким образом особо знания явы не продемонстрировать) Попробуйте тут по сайту поискать вопросы про калькуляторы - вроде были норм ответы как их на яве прямо делать, без JS

Comment: благодарю! Появился вопрос не по теме: не могу объявить `JSONObject`, кодом `JSONObject sa = new JSONObject();` - выдаёт `Stub!`

Comment: @EgorRandomize, задайте отдельный вопрос, в комментах да по такому минимуму информации помочь почти невозможно

Comment: да меня ограничили вот...)

Comment: @EgorRandomize, ну... Придётся, видимо, подождать)