# Как использовать функцию eval в android studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, eval

В android studio нет функции eval(),  как и scriptenginemanager, установка библиотеки jrs-223 то же не помогает, так можно ли каким то другим способом использовать функцию eval в android studio?

Comment: Попробуйте отсюда ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568480/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2-java/568512#568512

Comment: Если вам нужно только математические выражения вычислять то можно поробовать использовать [mxparser](https://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/simple-expressions/), вот [он на maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariuszgromada.math/MathParser.org-mXparser/4.3.3). Я сам не пользовался, по этому не знаю работоспособность этого решения под андроид.