# Можно ли строку типа String использовать как математическое выражение?

Tags: java

Есть

```
String s = "30/2.5";
double d;
```

Можно ли как-то переменной d присвоить это выражение ?

В некоторых языках, мне сказали, что это можно, а в JAVA можно?

Comment: Посмотрите тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/568512/17609

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если без использования библиотек, например javascript интерпретаторов, то придется разбирать эту строку (распарсить её), самому преобразовать строковые записи операндов в числа (из String в int, "30" -> 30), распознать математические операции и затем, следуя их приоритету выполнить вычисления. Например, можно вычислить выражение с помощью алгоритма Бауэра и Замельзона или алгоритма Рутисхаузера (http://algolist.ru/syntax/parsear.php).

Comment: я так и сделал. распарсил и все считается, но мне важно было узнать можно ли было сделать проще. За алгоритм спасибо. познавательно.